# Rails Test w/ Minitest Reporter - NoMethodError: undefined method + ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, minitest

I am learning Rails and very new to testing but so far I've managed to build something with minimal errors. However, the issue I am running into is that my tests are complaining for methods that cannot be found and no route matching.

To my understanding tests should be run frequently based [Hartl's - Railstutorial 3.3](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/static_pages#sec-getting_started_with_testing). Many StackO threads and online articles seem to pertain to utilizing test suites I don't use like RSpec, etc...so the test configurations are confusing. My testing suite is set up similiar to [Hartl's - Railstutorial 3.3](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/static_pages#sec-getting_started_with_testing) and below are the gems loaded for testing.

```
gem 'better_errors', '~> 2.1.1'
gem 'binding_of_caller'
gem 'minitest-reporters', '1.0.5'
gem 'mini_backtrace',     '0.1.3'
gem 'guard-minitest',     '2.3.1'
gem 'ruby-prof'
```

---

> **NoMethodError: undefined method**

```
Error: (_I have two error similar errors to below_)
ServicesControllerTest#test_should_get_index:
NoMethodError: undefined method 'services' for nil:NilClass
    app/controllers/services_controller.rb:6:in 'index'
    test/controllers/services_controller_test.rb:9:in 'block in <class:ServicesControllerTest>"
```

**Services Controller**

```
def index
  @services = current_tech.services
end
```

**services_controller_test.rb**

```
require 'test_helper'

class ServicesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  setup do
    @service = services(:one)
  end

  test "should get index" do
    get :index
    assert_response :success
    assert_not_nil assigns(:services)
  end
end
```

I believe the reason I am receiving this error is because of `Devise`.
If I were to setup the following index action below, the test will pass.

```
def index
  @services = Tech.first.services
end
```

How do I correct this so that this test passes?

---

> **ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"tech"}**

```
Error:
CarsControllerTest#test_should_get_show:
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"cars"}
    test/controllers/cars_controller_test.rb:5:in `block in <class:CarsControllerTest>
```

**Rake routes** *pertaining to cars*

```
tech_cars POST - /techs/:tech_id/cars(.:format) - cars#create
car GET - /cars/:id(.:format) - cars#show
```

**Routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do  

  devise_for :customers, controllers: { sessions: 'customers/sessions' }
  devise_for :techs, controllers: { sessions: 'techs/sessions' } 

  resources :techs, :only => [:index, :show], shallow: true do
    resources :cars, only: [:show, :create]
  end

  resources :services, :garages

  root "home#index"

end
```

***cars_controller.rb***

```
class CarsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_car

  def show
    @garage = Garage.find(params[:id])
    @tech = @tech.service.car.id
  end

  def create
    @garage = Garage.create(tech_first_name: @car.service.tech.first_name,
                                  customer_id: current_customer.id,
                                  customer_street_address: current_customer.street_address,
                                  customer_city: current_customer.city,
                                  customer_state: current_customer.state,
                                  customer_zip_code: current_customer.zip_cod)

    if @garage.save
      redirect_to techs_path, notice:  "Working" 
    else
      redirect_to techs_path, notice:  "Uh oh, flat tire" 
    end
  end

  private

  def set_car
    @car = Car.find(params[:id])
  end

  def car_params
    params.permit(:service_name, :garage_photo)
  end
end
```

**cars_controller_test.rb**

```
require 'test_helper'

class CarControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "should get show" do
    get :show
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

**cars.html.erb** (only links on page)

```
<%= button_to 'View Garage', tech_cars_path(tech_id: @car.service.tech.id, id: @car) %>
<%= link_to 'Back to tech', tech_path(@car.service.tech.id) %>
```

As you may gather, I am building a `Garage` not a `Car` object within the `Cars` controller. Would this be a problem for tests? My application functions fine as is. On a side note, I am also having difficulty trying to associate `car_params` strong params for instance variables but that's another StackO post.

---

***test/test_helper.rb**

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'
require "minitest/reporters"

Minitest::Reporters.use!

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all

  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
end

class ActionController::TestCase
  include Devise::TestHelpers
end
```

---

Is there something I am missing or haven't configured correctly?

Please know my application appears to be working fine, it's just I would like to suppress these tests errors.

Please advise on how to get these test errors to pass.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**First issue:** Your feeling is correct.  Devise comes with `Devise::TestHelpers` which you've mixed into `ActionController::TestCase` in your test helper file.  One of the methods it provides is `sign_in` which lets you spoof a logged in user as part of your test.  Assuming you've got a model called `Tech` and you're following standard Rails conventions, you'll need to add something like:

```
sign_in techs(:some_tech)
```

to either your `setup` block or directly into your test body before the call to `get :index`.  That will ensure that `current_tech` returns something non-nil and remove the immediate NoMethodError.

**Second issue:** Your `:show` action expects to receive the ID of a known `Car` as part of the URL.  Replace your current invocation of the controller with:

```
require 'test_helper'

class CarControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  setup do
    @car = cars(:some_car)
  end

  test "should get show" do
    get :show, id: @car.id
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi Chris, #1 - Thank you for your response. I was unaware of fixtures because Im very new to testing. Going through [Hartl's - tutorial 3.3](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/static_pages#sec-getting_started_with_testing), Hartl doesnt explain anything about fixtures. After receiving your response I continued to have errors. After doing some digging, I needed to include `setup do` w/ `@service = services(:one)` in the test. Then added the `@service = services(:one)` above the `get :index`. This returned no errors. :)

Comment: Is there I reason why I cannot modify the `one:` say to something more meaningful for example `service_test` to reference in the `services.yml`? I would like to be able to do something like `@service = services(:service_test)` and `sign_in techs(:service_test)` but the test complains.

Comment: For #2 - I've added what you posted - ' @car = cars(:one)' and  ` get :show, id: @car.id` but am still receiving errors. . The errors are: ` ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"create", :controller=>"cars"}` and `NoMethodError: undefined method `tech' for nil:NilClass`. I figured adding `setup do` - `@tech = techs(:one)` and `sign_in techs(:one)` above the `get :show, id: @car.id` but it's still producing errors. Please advise.